# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in svelte/sapper

Tags: javascript, fs, svelte, sapper

Trying to create a blog-like application using svelte/sapper and so I'm currently writing the post to a file as a JSON object. However, when I try and use fs, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

The file below is in the src/routes folder and is what handles the file writing function:

_write.js

```
function writeFile(obj) {
  var fs = require("fs");
  fs.writeFile('C:/Users/Toby/Documents/GitHub/political-web/src/routes/_posts.js', 'const posts = ' + obj + '; export default posts;', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Done!');
  });
}

export default writeFile;
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running your code in Node.js? Outside of Node.js, `require` does not exist. Also, I believe you should always do all your require/import stuff at the beginning of your module, not inside a function. From what I know, Node.js does not support `import` and `export`, and browsers don't have access to the file system. I don't think what you are doing can be made to work.

Comment: @connexo Hmm okay, do you know how/if it's possible to pass a variable to a node.js file from a svelte component, and also what makes a js file a node.js file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're getting that specific error — `require` *should* be defined when that code runs, unless you're somehow importing it in your client app (e.g. via a component).

Assuming that's not the case, and you're only importing `_write.js` from server code, rewrite it like this:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

function writeFile(obj) {
  fs.writeFile('C:/Users/Toby/Documents/GitHub/political-web/src/routes/_posts.js', 'const posts = ' + obj + '; export default posts;', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Done!');
  });
}

export default writeFile;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, though I'm still having an issue as I'm getting the error `Failed to resolve module specifier "fs".` In terms of importing it into my client app, I am importing the function writeFile into a svelte component, if that counts. If so, I was wondering how I can  access the writeFile function from a svelte component? As the intention is to write variables gained from the component to the file. (might be going about this the wrong way as I am still fairly new to js frameworks)

Comment: You can't access `fs` from client code. Instead, create a server route (https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Server_routes) with a `post` export, and post data to it (`fetch('my-server-route', { method: 'post', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify(data) }).then(...)`)